# Get all the PHP variables and its value

Tags: php

Is there any method to get all the PHP variables and its value in a page ?

I searched for it and couldn't find one.

Eg:

```
$a = 10;

$b = $a + 5;
```

What I am looking for is a method like

`get_all_var()` gives output:

```
$a = 10

$b = 15
```

Comment: Check out get_defined_vars() http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`get_defined_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)